# Wordpress Ajax Form CSV Price Request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, csv

I am creating a card calculator form where you can select a card type and select a quantity and a price is returned.

I am using a csv file for the pricing and I have it all working great. as a simple HTML Form displayed through a shortcode in WordPress.

```
<?php
// Get CSV 
$ch = fopen($standard_csv, "r");
$header_row = fgetcsv($ch);

// Get array of rows
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($standard_csv));

// Remove first row (header row) as we already have this separately
unset( $rows[0] );
?>


<!-- The Form -->
<form action="" method="post" name="calc" id="calc">

    Type: 
    <select name="card" id="card">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <?php
        // Remove first blank cell from $header
        unset( $header_row[0] );
        foreach ( $header_row as $key => $card ){
            echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $card . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>


    Quantity: 
    <select name="quantity" id="quantity">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <?php
        foreach ( $rows as $key => $row ){
            echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $row[0] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>

    </select>


    <input type="submit" name="get-price" value="Get Price!">

</form>

<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['get-price'] ) ){
    $card = $_POST['card'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    echo 'Price: £' . $rows[$quantity][$card];
}
?>
```

This is great but I want to display the returned price using AJAX so I do not have to refresh the page when a user requests a price for their chosen card and quantity.

I have my scripts enqueued like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );
wp_localize_script( 'custom_script-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),

add_action('wp_ajax_get_price', 'get_price');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_price', 'get_price');



function get_price(){

        $card = $_POST['card'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        return 'Price: £' . $rows[$quantity][$card];

}
```

I have this in my Javascript File

```
$('#calc').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var card = jQuery('#card').val();
            var quantity = jQuery('#quantity').val();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    action: 'get_price',
                    card: card,
                    quantity: quantity
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (errorThrown) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
    });
```

I have totally confused myself and I have tried to follow many tutorials, but I just cant work out the correct logic to be able to output a price from the CSV file using AJAX without reloading the page.

I know this code is totally not right, but please any help to set me in the right direction would be extremely appreciated.

I just need help understanding the logic on how to handle passing the variables and prices between the ajax and the php function in order to return a price from the CSV File.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't return from ajax - exit.

Replace `return 'Price: £' . $rows[$quantity][$card];`

with

`wp_die('Price: £' . $rows[$quantity][$card]);`

Best wishes,
Mitchell

Comment: Hello Mitchell and thank you for kindly assisting. I tried that and I have progress! However in my success function I am console logging the data, console.log(data); but it logs the entire page of HTML in the console for some reason?

Comment: 1) Please accept answer.  2) I'm not sure why console.log(data) would show anything but the returned value.

Comment: I will accept the answer as you got me headed in the right direction Mitchell so thank you for taking the time, it means a lot. I have now figured it out and got it all working :)

Comment: Thank you.  I wish I understood console.log() problem.